# URDF question: origin

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone tell me

```
<origin xyz="${x_loc} ${y_loc} ${z_loc}" ...>
```

means what? In my view it is number like 0,1 that should be after `xyz=`, but not the `${x_loc}` thing.

Additionally, I'm trying to mount an arm on turtlebot in URDF, is it OK to add turtlebot pan's origin parameter to origin parameter of arm base link? Or there exist other ways?

Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154756/urdf-question:-origin/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Re: your first question, you can do two things. First, you can put in actual values, e.g.,

```
<origin xyz="0.13 0.4 1.2">
```

Alternatively, you can use xacro. What you posted was URDF with xacro markup in it. With xacro, you can define values like this:

```
<xacro:property name="x_loc" value="0.13" />
<xacro:property name="y_loc" value="0.4" />
<xacro:property name="z_loc" value="1.2" />
```

...and then do

```
<origin xyz="${x_loc} ${y_loc} ${z_loc}">
```

See this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thanks, Tom. But the second question is more confusing and important for me. Would you pls help me out of this? Any suggestions or ideas are welcomed!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-22**:
I apologize, but I don't quite understand what your second question is asking. I'm afraid I haven't worked with the TurtleBot before. If you're trying you mount an arm on the robot, I'm guessing you'd define the link and then define the joint. Can you post some URDF code?

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-22**:
No sorry at all. The link between arm and turtlebot has been found. But I still cannot understand deeply of the tricks described in the Tutorial you provided. I haven't learnt XML before. I don't know whether this learning matters more? Or do you have other advices? Thanks!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-22**:
I would:

1. Go through an XML tutorial.
2. Go through the regular URDF tutorials, but ignore anything to do with xacro. Perhaps put together some sample robot models. This will help you understand why xacro is so useful.
3. Go through the xacro/URDF tutorial.

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-22**:
Thanks for your help!